# SSL is breaking my htaccess file in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, google-compute-engine

My .htacess file is vital not only for redirection but for the look of the site. I'm not sure why the developers of this theme did this but I can't change that.

If you navigate to http://akcrossfit.com you'll see the site as it should be. When you navigate to https://akcrossfit.com you'll see the site without styling and any navigation leads to a 404 error.

Here is my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^other/(.*) /wp-includes/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^file/(.*) /wp-content/uploads/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ext/(.*) /wp-content/plugins/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^skin/main\.css //index.php?style_wrapper=1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^skin/(.*) /wp-content/themes/richer-child/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^richer/(.*) /wp-content/themes/richer/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^skin_main/(.*) /wp-content/themes/richer/$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^ajax /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^wp-content/themes/richer-child/screenshot\.png|readme \.html|license\.txt|wp-content/debug\.log|wp-includes/$ /nothing_404_404 [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any idea what to change to fix this issue? The site is being hosted on Google Cloud Compute Engine. Thanks in advance for the help

Here's my VHost config (at least the part that's relevant to this topic)
`<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName akcrossfit.com:443
        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>`

Comment: What do you see in your access log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to go to the site over https it redirects me to the non-https URL but I suspect the problem is with the WordPress address and site URL in `Settings >> General`.

When you view the site, the references to your CSS and Javascript files are going to be linked over http which will prevent some browsers from loading the insecure content.

If you want the site to be secure, change your WordPress address to the https URL so the resources and links use SSL.

EDIT:  After being able to see the site over https, it looks like all of your resources (js, images, javascript) are coming back as 404 errors.  It even looks like the .htaccess rewrite rules aren't working for posts and pages.  This is most likely due to an error with the VHost configuration for the SSL site.  Apache error logs may help but I'd look at the SSL vhost first to see how it differs from the main site.

EDIT 2:  The problem is now that in your `<Directory /var/www/>` section there is `AllowOverride None` which effectively disables the .htaccess rewrite rules from being applied.

Comment: Sorry about that... I had a plugin that was redirecting. There's only a couple pages on the site that needs to be secure so I'm not interested in securing the whole site.

I've done this before but not on Google Cloud.

Comment: @DarrenJackson i updated the answer, it looks like all of the site resources are coming back with 404 errors on the ssl host.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm going to look into this today and get back to you.

Comment: I now have the front page of the site looking the way it's supposed to (https://akcrossfit.com) since the theme no longer needs htaccess to point to the css file.

I'm sure the SSL is working or I'd get a 404 error on the front page.

But for some weird reason, https doesn't see the htaccess file because when you try and navigate, you get 404 errors on all interior pages.

Comment: Looks like the resources are loading properly now but the .htaccess file isn't being processed for the ssl vhost.  Is `AllowOverride None` set on the vhost or does it have the necessary `AllowOverride All` specified?  If it is none or not set, then Rewrite rules and other directives will be ignored by apache.

Comment: Just edited the original post to include the VHost config. Can you see the issue? I changed AllowOverride None to All and restarted apache but it didn't help.

Comment: @DarrenJackson Just saw that you got it working, I noted that the AllowOverride None in the /var/www/ Directory section probably was preventing the rewrite rules from being applied.